# UPDATE WHERE IN() mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, sql-update

I have a table called tableA containing two columns, 1,2. I am trying to remove from column 1 a value depending on whats in the array. If that value exists twice, I want to set col1 as `col1 = col1 - 2`.

I could use `UPDATE tableA SET col1 = col1 - 1 WHERE col2 IN (?); .. [arr]` and be on my way, if `WHERE IN ()` didnt ignore duplicate values on the array.

Let me also note that this isnt about primary or unique keys and there is no problem with duplicate values. Below is the query where X is where I need to fix.

```
UPDATE tableA SET col1 = col1 - X WHERE col2 IN (?); .. [arr]
```

I know I can loop for the arr and run a simple query like: `UPDATE tableA SET col1 = col1 - 1 WHERE col2 = ? ; .. [arr[i]]` each time but am trying to find a better way - if there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UPDATE ... JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tableA a
JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) cnt
      FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
            UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 2) x  -- here goes IN values
      GROUP BY id
     )s
  ON a.col2 = s.id
SET a.col1 = a.col1 - cnt;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=31f1bf700fa100b788b79f2bd29882dc)**

Comment: I have a bit of trouble understanding this line `SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 2)`, would you mind explaining it a bit.

Comment: @JohnJames The point is instead of `IN (1,2,3)` => `(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 3` In final query you don't use `IN` at all. That's the whole point of my approach.

Comment: Oh okay I see, thanks. I get an error unfortunately doing `FROM IN (?)`,  ... [arr] where arr = [1,1,2]; Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: @JohnJames  **As I said you don't use IN at all.** You need to rewrite it in your application layer (ORM) to generate `UNION ALL`.